# A man pushes an object how much work is being done by the object

Tags: energy, work

Suppose I push a box I know that the work done by me would be $ΔK$ but what would be the work done by the object itself, wouldn't it be negative as the force and displacement are at angle of 180°

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Newton's third law, the box does $-\Delta K$ work on you.

Comment: But what about the work done BY the object it should be −Δ  too right?

Comment: The work, done by the box, on you, is $-\Delta K$.

Comment: The work done only BY the box should be  −Δ of the box correct?

Comment: In the absence of other work-doing forces (e.g. friction), that would be correct

Answer (score 0):

Lets invoke Newtons third law here.

You push a box and the box pushes you with equal but opposite force.
Note that you are exerting a force on the box and the box on you. The box is not exerting a force on itself.

To show that the force on itself is always zero, use Newtons third Law again. Suppose one end of the box pushes the other end, but the the other end pushes back with equal but opposite force. Hence the net force on the object by itself is always zero.

Hence by definition a box cannot do work on itself.